# How to use NLog in a plugin

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I would like to use NLog in a plugin and use the configuration API to configure it.  However, since the LogManager is static, how can I do this without interfering with other plugins that are doing the same thing?

The samples I see of using the configuration API involve replacing  LogManager.Configuration entirely.  I could try modifying whatever existing configuration there is, but I'm not sure if that would be thread-safe.

Comment: You want to configure the logging from the plugin?  I would think that would be up to the main application.

Comment: @Inuyasha In this case I want each plugin to configure its logging separately.  You can also imagine a main application you don't have control over that doesn't provide a logging service, but you don't want to interfere with other plugins that use NLog.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
// This could got into a static constructor somewhere in the plugin to make sure it happens early
LoggingConfiguration config = LogManager.Configuration;
ColoredConsoleTarget consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget();
config.AddTarget("myplugin", consoleTarget);
LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("myplugin", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

// Whenever my plugin creates a logger it'll obtain it like this
var log = LogManager.GetLogger("myplugin");
log.Error("Some message.");
```

Answer (score 1):

NLog actually has a non-static mode, that is nice for plugins and running unit-tests in parallel.

The LogManager is an interface around a global LogFactory. But you can create your own local LogFactory for setting up your local configuration. It will run side-by-side with the global LogFactory.

```
// This could got into a static constructor somewhere in the plugin to make sure it happens early
LogFactory logFactory = new LogFactory();
LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();
ColoredConsoleTarget consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget();
config.AddTarget("mypluginconsole", consoleTarget);
config.AddRuleForAllLevels(consoleTarget, "myplugin")
logFactory.Configuration = config;

// Whenever my plugin creates a logger it'll obtain it like this
var log = logFactory.GetLogger("myplugin");
log.Error("Some message.");
```

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging